# how to match multiple colums of same table and select maximum match colums

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `student` as s1
LEFT JOIN `student` as s2 ON s1.mainsubject_id=s2.mainsubject_id WHERE s1.mainsubject_id=s2.mainsubject_id AND s1.mainsubject_id > 0 AND s2.mainsubject_id > 0 GROUP BY s1.id`
```

i have below student table

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mainsubject_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `subsubject_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `level_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `gender` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `temppassword` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `stripe_id` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

i want to get single record of equal or maximum match from 5 colums (mainsubject_id, subsubject_id, level_id, postcode, gender) in same `student` table.

what is the best way to get record form same table with maximum match form 5 colums

Comment: Okay, do think need to change database structure?, may you suggest me ? @Tim

Comment: use having instead of where